# How to find string elements in another string and remove them in PHP

Tags: php, string

### By example:

```
FirstString='apple,gold,nature,grass,class'
SecondString='gold,class'
```

---

the Result must be :

```
ResultString='apple,nature,grass'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the easy way (for sure there must be more efficient ones):

First of all, you may want to separate those coma-separated strings and put them into an array (using the [explode](http://co.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) function):

```
$array1 = explode(',' $firstString);
$array2 = explode(',' $secondString);
```

Then, you can loop the first array and check whether it contents words of the second one using the [in_array](http://co.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php) function (if so, delete it using the [unset](http://co.php.net/manual/es/function.unset.php) function):

```
// loop
foreach( $arra1 as $index => $value){
    if( in_array ( $value , $array2 ) )
        unset($array1[$index]); // delete that word from the array
}
```

Finally, you can create a new string with the result using the [implode](http://co.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php) function:

```
$result = implode(',' , $array1);
```

That's it :D

Comment: You've got explode and implode backwards.

Answer (score 2):

```
$first = explode(',',$firstString);
$second = explode(',',$secondString);
```

Now you have arrays and you can do whatever you want with them.

```
$result = array_diff($first, $second);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a function that can do it but you could always break up the strings and do a foreach on each one and do some string compares and build a new string. You could also break apart the second string and create a regular expression and do a preg_replace to replace the values in the string.